# Deleting redundant endpoints and subscriptions in AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I send notifications to Android devices using SNS and GCM. When the app is uninstalled the subscription is still there in AWS because we basically can't call `unsubscribe` as we don't know when the app is going to be uninstalled.
Now this results in lot of redundant endpoints and subscriptions in AWS. How to clean this up in a scalable way? 
I can run a lambda whenever a message was failed to deliver to an endpoint. But the failure doesn't contain any `subscription arn`, and the AWS docs mention to unsubscribe the subscriptions before deleting the endpoint.

`When you delete an endpoint that is also subscribed to a topic, then you must also unsubscribe the endpoint from the topic.`

- I can create a mapping between endpoints and subscriptions by calling
  `list-subscription` for the existing subscriptions, but what about
  new endpoints and subscriptions? The new endpoint created message
  doesn't contain and info about subscription arn. Updating the table
  by listing all the subscriptions every now and then is not scalable.
  Is there a better way?
- What will happen if I delete the endpoint without unsubscribing? Will
  the orphaned subscriptions get cleaned automatically?

Comment: Exactly the question I was about to ask! Any update yet?